# Composer throws error "Could not find package with stability stable."

Tags: php, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I have tried to publish a project with composer. The project resides at github, and are published through packagist.org.

But when I try to create my project with composer it fails with this error message:

> "Could not find package madskullcreations/simplicity with stability
>   stable."

I use the following command:

```
composer create-project madskullcreations/simplicity
```

The composer.json contains this:

```
{
    "name": "madskullcreations/simplicity",
    "description": "Website made simple!",
    "homepage": "https://madskullcreations.com",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-3.0-or-later",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "cakephp/cakephp": "3.5.*"
    }
}
```

My repository contains just one file for testing. What is wrong? I tried to remove the dependencies, the entire "require"-block, but no real change...

Beginner as I am, I don't even know where I would define the packages "stability", can't find anything at github or at packagist.

Please help me get this started!

---

**Working solution:**

I eventually got it working with the help from Flying, see his answer further down. Since I think it is a wee bit complicated to get composer up'n working, I try to put the steps I did to get it working here:

1. Create a repository at github.
2. Create a composer.json with your depencencies. Check it in.
3. *Release* it. There are a "Releases" link somewhere, use it and give the release a name.

Now, to skip the packagist.org step during your testing, follow these steps. It is not good style to publish a non-working solution (like I did) on packagist.org, and it's no fun at all to do all the steps necessary ten times over.

Create a local folder somewhere, and create a new composer.json file there.

Put something like this in it:

```
{
  "require": {
    "madskullcreations/simplicity":"dev-master@dev"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
       "type": "vcs",
       "url": "https://github.com/madskullcreations/simplicity" 
    }
  ]
}
```

Run the following command in your new folder:

```
composer create-project
```

It should now download and install your project.

And, read the error messages given by composer and make sure you understand them. They are useful. My headache was a missing PHP-extension (intl) and that I assumed it was using php version 7.1, while it actually listened to my requirement in the composer.json file, and used v5.6. (I have several php-versions installed in iis, but my fuzzy head did not consider that.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Packages stability requirement is defined into [`minimum-stability`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#minimum-stability) setting of `composer.json` of **your project**, not a `composer.json` of the external package.

Your [madskullcreations/simplicity](https://github.com/madskullcreations/simplicity) package have [no releases](https://github.com/madskullcreations/simplicity/releases) defined so the only branch that is available in it - is `dev-master` "release" (it can be seen at the right side of [package page](https://packagist.org/packages/madskullcreations/simplicity) on Packagist). This "release" have "dev" stability level.

Because of above if you're requiring this package into your project without either setting `minimum-stability: dev` or without specifying stability requirement for a package as

```
"require": {
  "madskullcreations/simplicity":"dev-master@dev"
}
```

(notice `@dev` into version requirement) it is correct behavior of Composer to complain about lack of compatible releases.

Also it is generally bad practice to publish your test packages into public registry like Packagist. Instead you should use direct repository specification into your `composer.json` as explained [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories). In your case it will be:

```
"repositories": [
  {
     "type": "vcs",
     "url": "https://github.com/madskullcreations/simplicity" 
  }
]
```

After specifying direct repository reference - it will be safe to remove your test package from Packagist unless you're really want to share it with open source community.

Comment: Thank's a lot, I didn't know it should be 'released' on github like that. Now the chain is working and my package is working. :) About this "repositories"-thing, it sounds sensible not to put dirt onto packagist. How can I test my package without publishing it? Should I put a composer.json file with just the "repositories"-array _locally_, and then run some composer-command? Can you give an example of a working json file?

Comment: Actually all necessary information is already available in my answer. You need to add `repositories` section into your `composer.json` and in this section you need to specify all additional sources, Composer should look for packages. Composer supports different types of sources (defined as `type`), the only requirement is that target url will have `composer.json` with package definition. So if you will copy/paste provided piece of Composer configuration into your project's `composer.json` and will require `madskullcreations/simplicity` - it should work.

Comment: Got it working, at last. :) Added a working solution to my question, hope it helps someone.